# C# - Automapper - Map element with condition

Tags: c#, arrays, automapper

I have two classes:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set;  }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }
};

public class Customer_
{
    public string FirstNam { get; set; }

    public string LastNam { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

And a mapping between the two with Automapper library :

```
Customer[] data =  new Customer[3];

var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Customer, Customer_>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstNam, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FirstName))
   .ForMember(dest => dest.LastNam, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LastName));

});

IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
Customer_[] desti = mapper.Map<Customer[], Customer_[]>(data);
```

It works, but how to map only the elements of my array data that meet a condition ? For example : map only the element who have a `Quantity > x`

Thank's

Comment: AutoMapper is not designed to "filter" a source collection.  Use Linq or some other method to filter _before_ you map.

Answer (score 1):

Typically I'd do this before you map into AutoMapper:

```
Customer_[] desti = mapper.Map<Customer[], Customer_[]>(
    data.Where(c => c.Quantity > 10).ToArray());
```

Don't try to put this sort of intelligence into AutoMapper, it's confusing and will lead to bugs.

Comment: I do this, is it really a mistake?

Comment: It's confusing for me anyway. I don't like to have too much logic inside mapping configuration.